# What does the "path" property mean in Photorealistic 3D Tiles?

Tags: google-earth

I'm trying to understand how the children URL's are generated for [google photorealistic 3D tiles](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/create-immersive-3d-map-experiences-photorealistic-3d-tiles). In each json file of the children we can see a "path" property consisting in a number that seems to be an index of some type. This index plus another information encoded to base64 is what the final URL looks like.

For instance:
`UlRPVEYubm9kZWRhdGEucGxhbmV0b2lkPWVhcnRoLG5vZGVfZGF0YV9lcG9jaD04NTgscGF0aD0yMDUyNzA2MDcxNTA0MCxjYWNoZV92ZXJzaW9uPTYsaW1hZ2VyeV9lcG9jaD03MDQ.glb`

corresponds to

`RTOTF.nodedata.planetoid=earth,node_data_epoch=858,path=20527060715040,cache_version=6,imagery_epoch=704`

After investigating a bit it seems NOT to be any morton or hilbert or S2cell index. The subdivisions of these tiles are clearly mapped to other slippy tiles scheme based on their BoundingBox. The index is formed with a number of 3bit values (so from 0 to 7). Does anyone know how to correlate these paths with XY tiles?